# When to use nested inner class in java?

Tags: java, inner-classes

When should I use nested Inner class? As far as I know, one of the times it's used when no other class needs it. But if some other class needs it even then should I use it, if it's too related to it's outer class or in that case it's best to keep it a separate class?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You use them when you need them ...

Comment: Check out the following Oracle recommendations: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/whentouse.html

Comment: This w3school [link](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_inner_classes.asp)  might be helpful too.

Answer (score 2):

you must read through [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) and you will understand why.

But basic answer is you use those to ensure those are not visible outside of desired scope of visibility and are available with their parent classes only.